# Complete elliptic integrals

Tags: special-functions, elliptic-integrals

Is there a simple way to relate complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind of the form

$$
K(1/m)\,,\quad K(-m)\,,\quad E(1/m)\,,\quad\text{and}\quad E(-m)
$$

to $E(m)$ or $K(m)$. Here, $K(m)$ and $E(m)$ are complete elliptic integrals of the first and second kind, respectively and $m$ is a real number.

Answer (score 0):

[DLMF 19.7.3](https://dlmf.nist.gov/19.7#E3) gives
$$K(1/m)=\sqrt m(K(m)-iK(1-m))$$
$$E(1/m)=\frac1{\sqrt m}(E(m)+iE(1-m)-(1-m)K(m)-imK(1-m))$$
DLMF 19.7.5 gives
$$K(-m)=\frac1{\sqrt{1+m}}K\left(\frac m{1+m}\right)$$
$$E(-m)=\sqrt{1+m}E\left(\frac m{1+m}\right)$$
Here $m$ is the parameter.